# Convolution equation equals a constant

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, integral-equations

How would you solve this?

[image]

I did the standard way of solving questions like these - I took the Laplace of both sides and used the convolution identity. But the solution I got, $f(t)=3+t^2/2$, does not satisfy the integral equation, nor does it satisfy the initial conditions. I have a feeling that the derivative includes the Dirac delta function, but I'm not really sure how to find this. Any help will be much appreciated.
Here is my working out.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvPS4.jpg)

Comment: Can you please share your full try?

Comment: @SeanRoberson I've added my working out.

Comment: can someone please help

Comment: @mathboyexpert1010 You have a convolution of $g_1$ and $g_2$ where $g_1(z) = \cos(z) \cdot 1_{[0,\infty)}(z)$ and $g_2(z) = f'(z) \cdot 1_{[0,\infty)}(z)$. In your attempt I think that you missed the indicator functions. Maybe you should try it again, this time including these indicator functions.

Comment: @shalop Those indicator functions don't change the value of the Laplace transforms though.

Comment: Of course multiplying an indicator will change the laplace transform.

Comment: @shalop I'm not sure how to do this then...